# Disable macro buttons when sheet is protected?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using shapes as macro buttons in Excel.

Even when a sheet is protected, users can click on the buttons in that sheet.

Is it possible to make it so that buttons become "disabled" when the sheet is protected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement this at the beginning of every macro associated with buttons:

```
If Activesheet.ProtectContents = True Then 
  Exit Sub
End if
```

Comment: Thx for fixing the code  :). Hope the general idea helped you